# Initialising Struct in C using Parameters

Tags: c, struct, casting, warnings

(Fairly new to C)
I have a struct I am trying to initialise and populate with variables. Defined by:
(I cannot edit the definition of the struct)

```
typedef struct metadata {
    off_t size;                 
    char name[50];  
} metadata_t;
```

When trying to initialise a 'metadata' object using parameters in a function defined by:

```
send_metadata(off_t file_size , char* output_file){

    metadata_t meta = {file_size , output_file};
    //send metadata to....

}
```

However get warning:

```
initialization of ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     metadata_t meta = {file_size , name_buf};
                                    ^~~~~~~~
```

What is the proper way to accomplish what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not initialize an array from the pointer (`meta = {file_size , output_file};` tries exactly that).

Instead, you should **copy** string value, like that:

```
metadata_t meta;

meta.size = file_size;
strncpy(meta.name, output_file, sizeof(meta.name));
meta.name[sizeof(meta.name) - 1] = '\0';
```

Note how `strncpy` is used (which limits the number of characters copied to array), and how the last element is set to null terminator, since `strncpy` would not do this if it had to truncate the string.

Comment: Exactly the sort of answer I was hoping for. Thankyou